# Did my avatar just change to a generic one, but only on SO?

Tags: support, profile-picture, gravatar

On all other sites (Electrical Engineering, Video Production, Emacs, etc.) my avatar looks like me:

[image: https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/1b6d0554634ccfb064a26c6de5faf6b4?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG]

But today I noticed that on SO, my avatar looks like a generic gravatar:

[image: https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/380055f498e6928d39c91e5a9477fb22?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1]

What happened,and how do I prevent this from happening again?

Comment: also relevant [*I'm working on restoring it network-wide - we ran a backfill that did something... unexpected*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367454/why-has-communitys-profile-picture-changed#comment1224231_367454)